# Family of sets without 2 disjunct elements, prove the statement

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose, that the $F \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ family of sets doesn't have two disjunct elements. Prove, that there is always an $F' \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ family of sets, which contains $F$, $F'$  has no disjunct elements either, and $|F'| = 2^{n-1}$.

What I tried: If $F$ doesn't have two disjunct elements, then no matter how I choose $2$ subsets from $F$, they have an element which is in both of them. If we choose a random $S$ set, then $S^c$(complementary set), $S \in F$ and $S^c \in F$ can't occur both, since if we choose these two set, they have no element which can be found in both of them. In this case, we can only choose only one from the original sets, or the complementary sets, so our maximal number of elements can only be $\frac{2^n}{2}=2^{n-1}$.

I can show a set which has that amount of elements. Let us have $2^{[n]}$ and choose a fix $E$ subset from it. We make $F$ in this method: Every subset of $F$ must contain $E$. In that case the number of elements in $F$ is $2^{n-1}$.

I just have no idea how to prove, in general, that for every $F$ which has the attitude above, I can found such $F'$. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose S is a set not in F.  If we can legally add S to F then we do.  If we can't legally add S to F then there exists some T in F such that S and T are disjoint (or disjunct as you say).  If that is the case, what can we say about the relationship between T and S's compliment?  If you can show that you can add S's compliment to F instead of S then you will be done...